# Python 3 (3.5) - Load a very large dictionary fast

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, memory

I have the problem that I need to create a very large dictionary (from Google GloVe, 400'000 entries made up from one key and a vector of 100 elements per key) when I run my script (for machine learning). The issue here is that it takes about 60--160 seconds to create the dictionary, but I would need to decrease this by **a lot**, preferably down to below 10 seconds. I currently have two ways of doing this (the numbers and letters are all random, not the ones shown below):

1) Run the following (takes about 60 seconds):

```
file_input = codecs.open('dictFile.txt', 'r', 'UTF-8')
myDict = {}        

for line in file_input:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.split(' ')
    if len(line)==0:continue
    token = line[0]
    vector = np.array([float(x) for x in line[1:]])
    myDict[token] = vector
file_input.close()
```

Where dictFile.txt have the following structure:

```
a 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 100
b 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 100
...
c 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 100
```

2) Run the following (takes about 160 seconds)

```
readFile = open('dictFile.py', 'r', encoding='utf8')
    for line in readFile:
        exec(line)
```

Where dictFile.py is formated as such:

```
import numpy as np

myDict = {}
myDict['a']=np.array([1, 2, 3, ... , 100])
myDict['b']=np.array([1, 2, 3, ... , 100])
...
myDict['c']=np.array([1, 2, 3, ... , 100])
```

The issue is that i cannot simply run

```
from dictFile import myDict
```

since this makes me run out of memory (and hangs my PC for about 10 minutes). Can anyone give me a suggestion of how to speed up the process? How can I as fast as possible gain access/create my dictionary? Is there any possible way to create it once and save it for future use?

Appreciate all answers!

Comment: Unless your program frees a lot of memory before you try to `exec` the file, I don't see how your approach does not also cause an out-of-memory error.

Comment: My guess is it's the creation of 400,000 numpy arrays that is slow, not the dictionary. You could try turning those arrays into generators that only become arrays on demand, that way the dictionary just holds generators instead of having to parse all of those lines at once.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to wait until a certain point in your program to actually allocate the `dict`, define a function that creates and returns it so that you can control when it gets called.

In `dictFile.py`:

```
import numpy as np

def create_mydict():
    myDict = {}
    myDict['a'] = np.array(...)
    ...
```

Then in your code,

```
myDict = dictFile.create_mydict()
```

If you really need `myDict` to exist as a module-level variable, then you can declare it as such and have `create_mydict()` populate the global.

```
import numpy as np

myDict = None
def create_mydict():
    global myDict
    myDict['a'] = ...
    ...
```

You can also conditionally call `create_mydict` as needed:

```
if dictFile.myDict is None:
    dictFile.create_mydict()
```

This requires you to use `import dictFile`, not `from dictFile import myDict`, as the latter creates a separate global name from `dictFile.myDict` that isn't affected by the call to `create_mydict`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion - I'll try it out!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to read your file by chunks of (400000/CPU_core) lines, between multiple threads.